# How do I use async library calls in AWS Lambda functions?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use a nodejs-8.12 library created by lob.com in an AWS Lambda function. The code looks like this:

```
'use strict';


module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  var imagine all the variable defined here

  console.log(front)
  console.log(r)

  // Create the address
  Lob.addresses.create({
    name: r.name,
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    address_line1: r.address1,
    address_line2: r.address2 || "",
    address_city: r.city,
    address_state: r.state,
    address_zip: r.zipcode,
    address_country: r.country
  }, function (err, address) {
    console.log(address)
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      Lob.postcards.create({
        description: '',
        to: address.id,
        front: front,
        back: back,
      }, function (err, postcard) {
        var card = postcard
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log('The Lob API responded with this postcard object: ', postcard)

        }
      });
    }
  });


  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};
```

Now I ran the lamda function and I could see logging before I ran the code above always executed. But none of the console logs within the code above executed before the lambda shutdown.

I'm realizing now that the function isn't waiting for any of the callbacks. I read somewhere that you need to use `invoke` when call async functions, but i'm not sure how I would do that when using external libraries which are managing the requests themselves. Is there a way to tell the function to wait for all this to finish?

Comment: Is that the whole code? I can't see the function entry point.

Comment: no, this is what is inside the function handler. all of the code around this part works fine. i'm able to see the logs in AWS. but the function never waits for this bit of code to finish before shutting down

Comment: okay I updated with more of the function code.

Comment: Assuming `Lob.addresses.create()` is asynchronous, then the problem is that execution continues to the return statement without waiting for the async results, which exits the lambda.

Comment: I was able to get further. by adding `await` in front of `Lob.addresses.create()` it waits for that to finish. but adding `await` in front of `Lob.postcards.create` doesn't every resolve. even though I made it's parent function an `async` function

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your problem as follows:

```
    'use strict';


    module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

        //Create the address
        var promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
            Lob.addresses.create({
                name: r.name,
                email: '',
                phone: '',
                address_line1: r.address1,
                address_line2: r.address2 || "",
                address_city: r.city,
                address_state: r.state,
                address_zip: r.zipcode,
                address_country: r.country
            }, function (err, address) {

                if(err) return reject(err)

                return resolve(address)
            });
        })

        promise.then((data) => {

            Lob.postcards.create({
                description: '',
                to: data.id,
                front: front,
                back: back,
            }, function (err, postcard) {

                var message = 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!'
                var code = 200

                if(err)
                {
                    message = err;
                    code = 500
                }

                return callback(null, {
                    statusCode: code,
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        message: message,
                        input: event,
                    }),
                });

            });
        }).catch(reason => {

            return callback(null, {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: reason,
                    input: event,
                }),
            });
        })
    };
```

I used promises for resolve the first call, once that resolve it, i called the second method.

I prepare you an example (async, callback and promise):
[Here working](https://github.com/ns4lin4s/stackoverflow/tree/master/53072843)

Just you must adapt your code!

Hope to help you!

Comment: the function never waits for the second promise with the example above, unfortunately.